# Automatically generate forms using angularjs and django rest framework

Tags: python, angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I've noticed, that Django REST framework provides metadata for API endpoint
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/

Is there common way to generate forms in angularjs without writing a lot of code?

I've seen [this](http://davidmburke.com/2014/07/06/django-rest-and-angularjs-a-dont-repeat-yourself-approach/) article, but it looks like it's just allow annotate forms, not automatically generate it.

To make this question more specific: is there a way(or library) to generate HTML form with appropriate field types, "require" attributes validation from the Django REST framework HTTP OPTIONS output?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [django-rest-formly](https://github.com/benzid-wael/django-rest-formly) with npm, it help you generate angular-formly 's form configuration for your Django REST Framework endpoints